# How to convert to sentence case each new line?

Tags: php, string, text, transform, capitalize

I'm working on a lyrics website. There is a `textarea` in the admin panel to inset a new song. How can I do the followings?

- Capitalize the first letter of each line
- Add a space at the end of each line

I tried `ucfirst(strtolower($str))` which only Capitalize the first letter of the whole word set since there are on periods in it. I know how to remove unnecessary hyphens, extra spaces, and html tags if any. What should I do? using `nl2br` and replacing `<br/>` with `\n` would do everything but capitalizing every new line.

---

**EDIT:**

```
<style>
    textarea { width:200px; height:300px; }
</style>

<form action="/t" method="post">
    <textarea name="txt"><?php echo $_POST["txt"]; ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
    <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
</form>

<?php
$text = $_POST["txt"];
$lines = explode("\n", $text);

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $line = ucfirst(strtolower($line)) . " ";
}

$goodtext = implode("\n", $lines);

echo "<textarea>$goodtext</textarea>";

?>
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Sample text a user enters in a textarea:

```
Sithsoi asdigoisad
aASDF asdgdguh asudhg
sadg asdg AAFA ASFA
```

The desired output :

```
Sithsoi asdigoisad[sapce]
Aasdf asdgdguh asudhg[sapce]
Sadg asdg aafa asfa[sapce]
```

*Note the capitalized first letter of each line and the [space] at the end of each line*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified with array_map():

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['txt'])) {
    $text = $_POST["txt"]; 
    $text = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $text);
    $lines = explode("\n", $text); 
    $goodLines = array_map('ucfirst', array_map('strtolower', $lines)); 
    $goodText = implode(" \n", $goodLines); 
    echo nl2br($goodText);
}
?>
```

Here's a phpfidle that proves it works:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/trr-dgu

Comment: Thanks. This work except there is no space at the end of each line. :(

Comment: Well, now the spaces are added as new lines, NOT at the end of each.

Comment: Err.... I'm using the `$_POST` data. **NOT** just a text string. see the `$text` of my code please

Comment: Well, again the spaces are added at the beginning. NOT at the end. How can I move that to the end of the each sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want here, you want each sentence to end with a space AND a newline ?

Comment: Yh. That's the idea. When a user adds some text, (i.e. a set of lyrics) I want to capitalize the first letter of *each new line* and add an space at the end of each new line before storing it in the DB

Comment: Then `implode(" \n", $goodLines)` does exactly that, I edited my answer to use that. The will join the array with a space and a newline between each element (line). Tell me if it works for you, and if it doesn'T work for you, please post a sample of what you are submitting (the POST) and the result you get.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The current code outputs exactly that. adding a nl2br() when outputting (from the DB) should present it to the end-user exactly as expected. What result are you gettuing with my script ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31501/discussion-between-sid-and-alex-info-net)

Comment: It's fine this time. Didn't have to use `nl2br()` as I'm echoing the `$_POST["txt"]` *inside a textarea*. Hence I'm taking the liberty to edit it out.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
<?php
$text = "your lyrics";
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$goodLines = array();

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    array_push($goodLines, ucfirst(strtolower($line)) . " ");
}

$goodText = implode("\n", $goodLines);
?>
```

Comment: It has to be `"\n"` or `PHP_EOL`, not `'\n'`. Backslashes escape only `'` inside single quotes.

Comment: @AlexanderCogneau. Thanks But still no luck. See the edit please

Comment: @Sid what is the output if you do it the way I suggested?

Comment: @AlexanderCogneau Changing `$line` won't affect the `$lines` array, so the `implode` will just return the original text. You'll probably need to create a new array, append each new `$line` to it, then `implode` that. Alternatively, iterate `$lines` by index, and replace the lines in-place.

Comment: @AlexanderCogneau In theory. In PHP 5.3+ you can do it in a one-liner: `$goodText = implode("\n", array_map(function($line) { return ucfirst(strtolower($line)) . " "; }, explode("\n", $text)));`

Comment: @AlexanderCogneau This time, lines are capitalized. but the ending space is not there. AInstead, there is another new line with a space between every line.

Comment: @Aya, I get an error message saying *unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'*

Comment: Err.... I'm using the `$_POST` data. **NOT** just a text string. see the `$text` of my code please